# Login problems in linux, session not starting

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I have problem with login system, in windows it works, but in linux session has not start, after login they navigate to page, but page is clear becouse session is not started.

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Cannot connect to databases!");
mysql_select_db("registered_users",$con);
$lietotajs = $_POST['login_lietotajvards'];
$parole = MD5($_POST['login_parole']);
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE lietotajvards='$lietotajs' and parole='$parole' LIMIT 1");
$row=mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($row == 1){
    session_start();
    $a=mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $_SESSION['user']=$a['vards'];
    $_SESSION['login_lietotajvards'] = $_POST['login_lietotajvards'];
    $_SESSION['epasts'] = $a['epasts'];
    $_SESSION['uzvards'] = $a['uzvards'];
    $_SESSION['vards'] = $a['vards'];
    $_SESSION['talrunis'] = $a['talrunis'];

    echo '
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location.href = "panel.php";
        </script>
    ';
}else{
    echo "
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
            window.location.href = \"../mani-sludinajumi.php\";
            alert('Lietotājvārds vai parole ir nepareiza, Mēģiniet vēlreiz! Vai arī jūs nēsat vēl šeit reģistrējies!');
        </script>
    ";
}
?>
```

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerabilities. Enjoy having your server pwn3d

Comment: Maybe your windows machine has `session.auto_start` enabled - http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start

Comment: – [A **highly** suggested read](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10)

Answer (score 0):

Always start session at the beginning of file..

```
<?php
session_start();
$con=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Cannot connect to databases!");
mysql_select_db("registered_users",$con);

//other code
```

Comment: Oops... How i miss that :/

Comment: Maybe for linux need put Cookie?